# Can't encrypt SanDisk 8GB

Tags: disk-utility, partition, encryption

I've formatted my SanDisk flash drive to a OSX Extended format with the GUID Partition Map. 
But when I go to encrypt the drive I continually get this error: 
"A partition, not a whole disk, is required for this operation."

The partition option in Disk Utility is not available for this drive. I'm using Disk Utility to format it.

I'm using OS X version 10.11.

Comment: Are you clicking on the partition you created and not the disk itself?

Comment: @IronCraftMan I'm right clicking on the disk in the Finder menu and clicking 'Encrypt SanDisk 8GB'.